# Maven resources/ in sibling modules

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, classpath

I have a issue with some tests in sibling modules.

I have the following folder in module 1 in resources/: sql/statements 
all the files in that folder is loaded with the following code:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sql/statements");
assert url != null;
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(url.getPath()),
    FileFilterUtils.suffixFileFilter("sql.xml"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
```

This works fine:

- inside intellij for the sibling module
- inside intellij in the module with the xml files
- with maven clean install in the module with the xml files

**but for some reason when I reference this class in a test in the sibling module it is unable to find the xml files when I run clean install from command line.**

how can I solve this?

edit: when it fails it print the follwing url path, which seem ok (?):
url: `jar:file:/home/<user>/.m2/repository/<path>/1.0.0/<jar-name>1.0.0.jar!/sql/statements`

Answer (score 0):

Check your POM files : you are probably only copying the resources in the build of your "sql/xml" module. Better move it up to the parent POM if you want to use it in sibling modules.

Comment: the other module has the sibling as dependency, I guess that should be ok? The parent POM does not have any resources - and I think it should stay that way.

Answer (score 0):

As for [**this**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) maven doc, test resources should be stored in

```
src/test/resources
```

But you can set parameter `testResources` to the same directory as main resources

```
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
               <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
         <testResources> 
         <resources> <!-- this is default setting -->
             <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory> 
                <filtering>true</filtering>
             </resource>
         </resources>
```

Comment: these resources are not only for tests, I want to use them in production code as well

Comment: @Vegard I understand. With this setting, you will have same resources in production and in tests